# Timezonelist contains entries in mixed language

Tags: c++, c, windows, utf-8

On windows, I am not able to set timezone to particular timezone. I use the win api SetTimezoneInformation to set it, it returns success even then the systems date/time control panel it is not updated.
Actual problem was caused when the timezone list contains few entries in one locale and few others in another locale resulting the timezone not being set correctly. If it contains entries in only one lang then the api works correctly.  My application simply reads the timezone from the registry.
I dont how to resolve this issue.
Is there anyother way to set the timezone in c/c++?